# JSON from yahoo financial API SyntaxError when is given as parameter to google chart table

Tags: javascript, json, yahoo-finance

I use yahoo financial API to get data from it and then I want to input the data in google chart, but it seems that I have a problem with the JSON  object. So, I tried everything which I read , but unfortunately still unsuccessful.
**Error**

> index.html:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at
>   position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at drawChart (main.js:18)
>       at Object.google.a.c.Ac (loader.js:155)
>       at Object.google.a.c.Pa (loader.js:155)
>       at f (loader.js:152)
>       at Object.google.l.m.kj (loader.js:229)
>       at Object.google.l.m.ce (loader.js:229)
>       at loader.js:228

**JavaScript**

```
google.charts.load('current', {
'packages': ['corechart']
});

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

var options = {
    'title': 'Today is not my day',
    'width': 400,
    'height': 300
};

var input = getData();

function drawChart() {
    var chartData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(JSON.parse(input));
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(chartData, options);
};

function getData() {
   dataArray = [
    ['Name', 'Volume'],
  ];

  var BASE_URL = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=";
  var yql_query = 'select * from yahoo.finance.quote where symbol in ("YHOO","AAPL","GOOG","MSFT")';
  var yql_query_str = encodeURI(BASE_URL + yql_query);
  var result = yql_query_str + "&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";

  $.getJSON(result, function(data){
    var object = data.query.results.quote;
    for (var i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
      var currentObj = object[i];
      var pushedArray = [currentObj.Name, parseFloat(currentObj.Volume)];
      dataArray[i+1] = pushedArray;
    }
    return dataArray;
  });
};
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/request.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" id="chart_div"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is written above, `getData()` synchronously returns `undefined`, so inside of `drawChart()` you're essentially trying to `JSON.parse(undefined)`, which leads to the `SyntaxError` you received (`JSON.parse()` casts `undefined` to the string `"undefined"`, which is invalid JSON).

`dataArray` is being returned from within the callback to `$.getJSON()` *after* the request returns; there is no way it could currently be accessible inside of the `drawChart()` function.

You need to refactor the code so that `drawChart()` is called after the `$getJSON()` request has returned, and so it has access to `dataArray` either lexically or through a closure.